# Files are corrupt after copying/streaming them from samba fileshare

Tags: networking, debian, hardware-failure, samba, file-corruption

I'm running Debian 12 with an smb file server installed. The Samba version is `4.17.12-Debian`. When I try watching any video from the share on any other machine in the network, there are significant glitches/artifacts that are not in the original. When I copy any one of the videos from the share to another machine, the SHA256 checksum of the file is different every time I copy it. I tried this with three different network cards (onboard, PCIe, and USB).

However, if I change my server's static IP address and access the samba share under the new address, videos look normal and copied files consistently have the same checksum as the original file on the server. Then, as soon as I reboot my machine, the issue is back even with the new address, until I change it again.

I tried setting up an SMB server on the same machine using a few other operating systems (including Windows 10) and the behavior was the same every time. The issue also persisted when I moved the video that I was trying to watch/copy to a different hard drive on the server.

I was not able to reproduce the issue on a different machine with the same software installed and using the same hard drive.

I'm not sure what to make of this. I was assuming it's a hardware issue but now I'm not so sure due to the IP changing workaround. What else can I do to investigate this further?

Comment: Does this still occur if you enable (and require) SMBv3 encryption in Samba? Normally SMB 'signing' would catch any network interface issues (unless you're deliberately using SMBv1 without signing enabled) – so if the corruption persists, it might instead indicate it's a memory or storage issue...

Comment: The one constant in all your tests and configurations is the operating system on your computer. If you have another security software installed than Windows Defender, try to disable it temporarily. Try also to test Windows integrity by running the commands [Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/7808-use-dism-repair-windows-10-image.html) and then [sfc /scannow](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2895-run-sfc-command-windows-10-a.html).

Comment: Configured my server to require encryption using `server smb encrypt`. Now videos only play a few frames at a time with several seconds of loading in between, and copying files fails with an unknown/unspecified error. The same goes when I require signing.

I set up an smb server on my laptop using Arch Linux and configured the same options, and both watching and copying files from there works without issues.

Also, trying to access the smb server using Arch Linux, Windows 11 or an app on my phone does not make a difference. The issue is there either way.

Comment: If you're not seeing any I/O errors in the server's dmesg, that strongly hints at a memory failure; what results do you get from booting into Memtest86? (Available on many Linux liveCDs.)

Comment: You are correct - I managed to narrow it down to one of my memory modules. That particular module alone does not cause any issues - they only appear whenever I combine it with any additional module. Memtest86+ passed several times without errors though, and when I tested my original RAM configuration (2x 8GB, including the faulty module) in another computer, I was not able to reproduce the issue. So there might be another problem with my hardware that also contributed to the behavior I was observing.